# How to use a created database class to query data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have difficulties to select data, and even to put data in my database when I use classes. Here are two examples, one works (without classes) and the other does not (with classes).
Let's start with the one that works.
In the file name `index1.php` we have these code lines.

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database","user","pass"); 
echo "Connection success "; 

$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email";
$email= "mail@gmail.com";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
//var_dump($stmt);
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count;
```

This returns $count = 2, which is true. I have 2 users in the database with `mail@gmail.com` as email.

Now to the case that does not work.
This is the file `Database.php`

```
<?php
 class Database{
        protected $pdo;
        protected static $instance; 
        
        protected function __construct(){
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            echo "success"; 
        }

 public static function instance(){
               if(self::$instance===null){
                  self::$instance = new self;
              }
              return self::$instance; 
            }

 public function __call($method, $args){
     return call_user_func_array(array($this->pdo, $method), $args);
       }  
    }
?>
```

And I use it in the file `index2.php`

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "pass");
define("DB_NAME", "database");

include_once "Database.php";

$pdo = Database::instance();

$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email";
$email = "mail@gmail.com";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count;
```

This $count returns `0`.And I get no error. I used `var_dump() and $stmt->debugDumpParams()` but could not found where the problem is). Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I have to ask... what's the point of wrapping PDO in a class like this in the first place? It seems very unnecessary.

Comment: For one: `"mysql:host".DB_HOST` is missing an equals-sign.

Comment: Thank you @DecentDabbler, that was the problem.